# browser closure confirmation on ext.net

Tags: extjs, ext.net

What I want to do is the following

```
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          return 'Dialog text here.';
          Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmación", "Seguro que quieres salir", function (btnText) {
              if (btnText === "yes") {                
                 App.direct.RegistrarAbandono();
              }
          }, this);
      };
```

that is, I want that if the person leaves the browser to be able to delete or do some action from the server and notify the person who will have some consequences for avandonar the form.

thank you very much

Comment: You cannot halt/pause window.onbeforeunload event.So no use of showing dialog box here.

Comment: AND A POSSIBLE SOLUTION? OR WAY TO DO WHAT I WANT?

Comment: Thing which can do is you can only change message present on beforeunload dialog box.And I think you should show some message like changes cannot be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, "beforeunload", function (e) {
                 Write your code here
        }, this, {});
```